Divisors of $n$ whose sum $n$ divides must have a subcollection that sums to $n$
When working on a problem the other day, I kind of assumed that if a permutation $\sigma \in S_{n\cdot m}$ has order $n$, then there exists a some coloring of $[n\cdot m]$ with $m$ colors that each appear exactly $n$ times that $\sigma$ preserves.
This seemed intuitive at first, but proving it has shown to be more challenging than initially thought. The equivalent statement that I was working with is:

Given some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if a collection $\mathcal{C} = \{a_i\}$ with $\forall i.\ a_i | n$ has the property that $n | \sum a_i$, then there exists some index set $I$ for which $n = \sum_{i \in I} a_i$

Are there any directions someone could point me in that might help prove (or disprove) this?

As I posted in my previous comment, the collection $C = [15, 10, 10, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1]$ with $n = 30$ is a counterexample to this statement.
In particular, we have $a_i \mid n$ for all $i$, we have $n \mid \sum_i a_i = 60$, and for any index set $I$, the sum $\sum_{i \in I} a_i$ is not 30.
